# mongodb - embedded field vs embedded document indexing

Tags: mongodb, indexing

So I'm wondering if I were to create an index on a document, will it also inherently create an index on the embedded fields as well?

So for the example:

```
{
  name: {
          first: "Yukihiro",
          last: "Matsumoto"
        }
}
```

If it was an embedded document index, will performing a search with:

```
   {
     "name.first": "Yukihiro",
     "name.last": "Matsumoto"
   }
```

cause it to search using an index, or will it be looking up the documents O(n)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, so long as the document isn't larger than the allowed index size - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/#create-an-index-on-embedded-document

You can check that a specific query is using an index with the 'explain' function on a query. The `"stage": "IXSCAN"` indicates it has used an index.

```
"winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                        "type" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "type_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                        "type" : [
                                "[\"teacher\", \"teacher\"]"
                        ]
                }
        }
}
```